# Running wordpress project on multi php xampp

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, web-development-server

im new to wordpress web dev, can you guys help me out hehe. so im installing xampp with php 8 in my windows and i need to host several wordpress project that worked on php 5.6 while the other ones are using php 7.3.
So i figured out i can install 2 php versions in my xamp, by doing this:

1. have a php version 7.3 in my /xampp folder, then configured the php.ini file to edit the extension_dir and some other config like this:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbRTa.png)
2. configure the httpd-xampp-conf to host the php v 7.3 in other port (i set mine to 8073) like this script below

then just like it, i was able to access http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php and http://localhost:8073/dashboard/phpinfo.php and they're both showing that i have php version 8 and 7.3.

my problem is, i cant open my wordpress project, so running either localhost/my-wordpress or localhost:8073/my-wordpress dont really give me anything except that the browser just keep loading. I really want to put an error log here but i dont know where to look, so im kinda blind here. Anyone know where did i go wrong? Thank you T_T

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/php7_3">

AllowOverride None

Options None

Require all denied

<Files "php-cgi.exe">

Require all granted

</Files>

</Directory>

Listen 8073

<VirtualHost *:8073>

UnsetEnv PHPRC

<FilesMatch "\.php$">

php_flag engine off

SetHandler application**/**x-httpd-php7_3

Action application**/**x-httpd-php7_3 "/php7_3/php-cgi.exe"

</FilesMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```